# WP7 Marketplace Test Kit

Tags: windows-phone-7

The Marketplace Test Kit shows two capabilities for my app:

ID_CAP_NETWORKING, and
ID_CAP_LOCATION

I use location (GPS), but I don't think that I use networking. How do I find out why the test detects networking in my app?

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the way the Marketplace Test Kit determines capabilities by looking at; `C:\Program Files (x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\Marketplace\Rules.xml` (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\Marketplace\Rules.xml` on a 32 bit machine). This details what assemblies, classes and methods will trigger various capabilities being required. It's pretty easy to eye-ball and determine why it's included the capability.

There's a bit more on the capability process detailed in the MSDN article [How to: Determine Application Capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180730%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). As noted at the bottom the `ID_CAP_NETWORKING` may be added if `Uri`s are being used in your code / XAML. You can try removing it from your `WMAppManifest.xml` but make sure you thoroughly test it after the fact.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I do use Uri's, but only to navigate to different pages in my app. Anyway, you have answered my question.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I use Uri's, but only for navigation to pages in my app. So it seems that you have nailed down my problem exactly. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Do you use third party dlls like Advertising SDK? It may wants to use it.

Grep your sourecode for:

- GamerServices
- WebBrowser control
- System.Net
- Smooth Media Streaming
- Absolute URLs (like  )